# How to dynamically input array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is a simple code where I want to print the elements of an array which are provided as input.

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;

        int *arr = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<arr[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    //code
    return 0;
}
```

**input:**

```
2
5
1 2 3 5
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10
```

**ouput poduced by this code**

```
123510
2
```

but this shouldn't be the output as it should produce the other array from 1-10.

There must be a silly  mistake but i don't know where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third line of input is missing a 4.

It's thus parsed as:

```
2  // two arrays
5  // first one size 5
1 2 3 5
10  // end of the first array
1  /* second one size 1 */ 2 /* end of the second array */ 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 
// the end is ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly! you just screwed up your input
in the first example u expect 5 numbers and only enter 4 and in the second example you expect 10 numbers and provide 9.
if u create an array with in[5] the highest index is 4 but since the index starts with 0, the total size is 5.
if that's why you're missing one element every time.